# Money change exam

Tags: java, performance, recursion

I was asked to create a method that would:

- Return a Change object or null if there was no possible change
- The "machine" has unlimited bills of: 2, 5 and 10
- The Change object must return the most minimal amount of bills possible

This was a question asked in codingame.com and wanted to investigate further on it:

```
package moc;

class Change {

    long coin2 = 0, bill5 = 0, bill10 = 0;
}

public class Test {

    static Change c = new Change();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Change m = optimalChange(19L);

        if (m == null) {
            System.out.println("no change possible ...");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Coin  2E: " + m.coin2);
        System.out.println("bill  5E: " + m.bill5);
        System.out.println("bill 10E: " + m.bill10);

        long result = m.coin2 * 2 + m.bill5 * 5 + m.bill10 * 10;

        System.out.println("Change given: " + result);
    }

    static Change optimalChange(long s) {

        if (s < 2) {
            return s == 0 ? c : null;
        } else {
            int decrementor = 0;

            if (s < 5) {
                c.coin2++;
                decrementor = 2;
            } else if (s < 10) {
                if (s % 2 != 0) {
                    c.bill5++;
                    decrementor = 5;
                } else {
                    c.coin2++;
                    decrementor = 2;
                }
            } else {
                c.bill10++;
                decrementor = 10;
            }

            return optimalChange(s - decrementor);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like there is no need to recurse or loop at all. If the change is odd, it must include a 5-bill (special cases are changes of 1 and 3, which are impossible to make). The rest would be given by 10-bills (there will be `change / 10` of them), and 2-bills (there will be `(change % 10) / 2` of them). BTW, this is exactly what your code is doing, but in a very long way.

That said, your second version makes the recursive call a tail recursion. This is good. However, Java does not support tail call elimination. This is not so good. I strongly recommend to eliminate it manually.

Comment: Re "this is exactly what your code is doing", not exactly. OP's code would fail for s = 11, because it would choose $10. Your algorithm would see that it is odd, choose $5, and then choose 3x $2 for the rest.

Comment: Re "Java does not support tail call elimination", I think what you mean is that it doesn't *require* it? Presumably a compiler can do it as an optimization if it doesn't change the behavior of the code?

Answer (score 3):

Others can give advice on algorithms, I'll leave yours as-is and just give a few stylistic pointers.

---

`Test` is a class responsible for displaying things, `Change` is a class responsible for dealing with logic relating to change. So `optimalChange` should go in `Change`.

---

`int decrementor = 0`

You can avoid initializing this, and then your IDE will tell you if there are any branches you forget to set it's value before using it. (You never actually want this to be zero -- infinite loop!)

---

```
        if (s < 2) {
            return s == 0 ? c : null;
        } else {
```

When you have an early return, you can avoid increasing the nesting level, which can make the code easier to read, by just dropping the `else` block.

---

```
            } else if (s < 10) {
                if (s % 2 != 0) {
                    c.bill5++;
                    decrementor = 5;
                } else {
```

You can avoid the nesting by checking for both conditions at the top level, followed by the second condition.

---

```
static Change c = new Change();
```

I moved this first to `Change` since `optimalChange` was already moved there, and it depended on it. Then it didn't make sense for `Change` to have a `static Change` member, since `optimalChange` won't be valid when called more than once, or if used by other threads. You want an instance of `Change` per call to `optimalChange`, and it makes sense for `optimalChange` to remain `static` so where to keep that state between recursions? A: I made a separate function for the recursive part.

---

```
package moc;

public class Test {

    static class Change {
        long coin2 = 0;
        long bill5 = 0;
        long bill10 = 0;
        
        public static Change optimalChange(long s) {
            return optimalChangeRecursive(s,  new Change());
        }
        
        private static Change optimalChangeRecursive(long s, Change c) {
            int decrement;
            if (s == 0} {
                return c;
            } else if (s < 2) {
                return null;
            } else if (s < 5) {
                c.coin2++;
                decrement = 2;
            } else if (s < 10 && s % 2 != 0) {
                c.bill5++;
                decrement = 5;
            } else if (s < 10) {
                c.coin2++;
                decrement = 2;
            } else {
                c.bill10++;
                decrement = 10;
            }
            return optimalChangeRecursive(s - decrement, c);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Change m = Change.optimalChange(19L);

        if (m == null) {
            System.out.println("no change possible ...");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Coin  2E: " + m.coin2);
        System.out.println("bill  5E: " + m.bill5);
        System.out.println("bill 10E: " + m.bill10);

        long result = m.coin2 * 2 + m.bill5 * 5 + m.bill10 * 10;

        System.out.println("Change given: " + result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As vnp said, it looks like for the specific constraints of this problem, there is an easier way without recursion.

However, for different parameter/denominations, this might not be the case.

I suggest writing more robust code without the extra if loops checking for parity, because those work specifically for this problem.

There is a small flaw in your algorithm. You assume that the least bills will be found by picking the largest bill every time. As you can see with your example of s=8, this is not always the case. At every recursive node, you have to try all possible options (I think. There might be an optimization you can do at this step. Perhaps you can prune if one option's a multiple of the other), in case the biggest option doesn't work out.

You can also do dynamic programming if you know that.

Comment: In this case, without the $1 available, 4x $2 really is the best you can do for $8. This problem is a simple one because amounts more than $10 you can always give a $10, until you have something less than $10. Then you can just enumerate the best solutions below $10.

Comment: @Jeremy, re "amounts more than $10 you can always give a $10": This doesn't work for $11, which requires 1 x $5 and 3 x $2.